# Approximate time synchronizer for Different message Types

Tags: ros, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am trying to incorporate message filtering in my code.
I need to subscribe to two topics and execute the callback when both topics get a message at the same time (or approximately).
This is what I wrote so far:

```
 /// Subscribers to the two topics
typedef message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> blobSubscriber;
typedef message_filters::Subscriber<std_msgs::Float32MultiArray> PCLSubscriber;
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, std_msgs::Float32MultiArray> sync_policy_classification;

void callback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& image, const std_msgs::Float32MultiArray::ConstPtr& object_coordinates)
{
   // Some stuff here
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  ros::init(argc, argv, "colour_classification");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  blobSubscriber blob_sub(n, "/object_detection/object_mask", 1);
  PCLSubscriber PCL_sub(n, "/PCL_wooden_shape_recognition", 1);;

  message_filters::Synchronizer<sync_policy_classification> class_sync(sync_policy_classification(10), blob_sub, PCL_sub);

  class_sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));


  return 0;
}
```

This is the part of my code that includes the message filtering stuff.

When I try to compile this I get a large number of errors, that have to do with the different types of the messages. I actually tried using sensor_msgs::Image for both messages and was able to compile without any issues.

So my question is: Is it actually possible to implement message filtering for different types of messages?
And if yes, is there something obviously wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221456/approximate-time-synchronizer-for-different-message-types/) by [thomai](https://answers.ros.org/users/25168/thomai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect that the compilation problem comes from using Float32MultiArray. This cannot work in principle as that message does not have a time stamp, so there is nothing to synchronize to.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thomai](https://answers.ros.org/users/25168/thomai/) on 2015-11-24**:
Yes, that was the problem!
Switched to geometry_msgs::PolygonStamped and compiled! :)

Thank you!